# Facebook Graph Latency

Tags: facebook, latency

The following code fragment

```
for($i=0;$i<60;$i++){
    $u[$i]=$_REQUEST["u".$i];
    $pic[$i] =imagecreatefromjpeg("http://graph.facebook.com/".$u[$i]."/picture");
```

}

is taking more than 90 seconds to execute on my new server. It was taking less than 15 seconds on my shared hosting server. However, on dedicated server it is taking more than 90 seconds.

The data center of my new server is Asia Pacific.

Please advice on how I can reduce this time of fetching images on the graph.

thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

Why not just request all the pictures' URLs in a single call?

`https://graph.facebook.com/?fields=picture&ids=[CSV LIST OF IDS]&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`

You'll then have a list of all the images and can fetch them all however you so wish

Comment: Since he’s using `imagecreatefromjpeg` I’d say he’s not only interested in the URLs (or at least getting/creating these is not the time-consuming part) – getting the actual image data is.

Comment: thanks and regards. This will not solve the problem as Cbroe pointed out, time consuming part is getting the jpg one by one

Answer (score 0):

> is taking more than 90 seconds to execute on my new server.

Well, for 60 HTTP requests that’s not *too* bad, I’d say.

> It was taking less than 15 seconds on my shared hosting server. However, on dedicated server it is taking more than 90 seconds.

Maybe the connection of your old server was just faster …?

> The data center of my new server is Asia Pacific.

Do you know by any chance, which one it was before?

> Please advice on how I can reduce this time of fetching images on the graph.

Do you have to request all these images in one go?

Maybe your app’s workflow (which we don’t know anything about yet) would allow for other approaches, like getting user images at a previous time (f.e. when a user starts using your app) and cache them locally, so that you don’t have to do 60+ HTTP requests in one go.

Comment: Many thanks for your response! Is there any way in php where i can use createimagefromjpeg in parallel?